# Chromecast not caching images

Tags: c#, jquery, caching, chromecast, google-cast

I am using https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster to cast a website from a C# windows service.
Everything is working except for the caching of images.

We are using jquery to set the background-image and in a Chrome browser, this image gets cached. Unfortunately, on the chromecast, the image is retrieved every time the page reloads.

The cache control is set to private.

Is this a known occurence and is there anything I can use to force the chromecast to cache the image?

Thank you
Kind regards

Comment: Please update your post to show the full set of cache headers for the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you expect the images to be cached across sessions, then that is not supported. Whenever each recevier app is loaded, it is similar to a incognito window that gets closed after each session.

You can preload images using JavaScript during a session.